# COMMUNITY SIP TCP/IP message flooding directed to SIP proxy

Tags: snort, flooding, sip

I have installed Snort IDS and most alarm is:

**"COMMUNITY SIP TCP/IP message flooding directed to SIP proxy"**

And i use home DSL Internet connection , should i be worried about this alarm ?

I have read [this](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/f.huici/publications/sipdos.pdf) article but i couldn't understand it completely?

I set firewall on my router and I've block WAN to LAN connections, how these kind of packet pass it inside ?!!

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you are using an old snort version? 
Please see here: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1469108.html

Otherwise it would be great if you refine your question with some Firewallrules (Inbound) or some PCAP Files from wireshark.